# Group Query by Column Name MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a table with the following schema

[image: QUERYSET]

But i need to export that info to another table but the result that i need must be like this

[image: RESULT]

where machine value must be from the name of one of the column names
everything must be for Sql Server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using [**`cross apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) with `values()` to unpivot your data:

```
  select v.Machine, v.Temperature, v.Humidity, t.Fecha
  from t
    cross apply (values ('DR673',DR673_T,DR673_H),('DR677',DR677_T,DR677_H)
      ) as v(Machine, Temperature, Humidity)
```

---

To dynamically generate the sql based on column names:

```
declare @cols nvarchar(max), @sql nvarchar(max);

set @cols = stuff((
   select distinct 
      ',(''' + left(C.name,charindex('_',c.name)-1) 
      + ''','+ quotename(C.name) 
      + ','+ quotename(left(C.name,charindex('_',c.name))+'H') 
      +')'
   from sys.columns c
   where c.object_id = object_id('dbo.t')
     and c.name like '%_T'
   for xml path (''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
  ,1,1,'');

set @sql = '
select v.Machine, v.Temperature, v.Humidity, t.Fecha
from t
  cross apply (values '+@cols+'
  ) as v(Machine, Temperature, Humidity)';

  select @sql as CodeGenerated;
  --exec sp_executesql @sql; /* to execute the dynamic sql */
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/NAOT80053

returns:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                     CodeGenerated                                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     select v.Machine, v.Temperature, v.Humidity, t.Fecha                              |
|     from t                                                                            |
|       cross apply (values ('DR673',[DR673_T],[DR673_H]),('DR677',[DR677_T],[DR677_H]) |
|       ) as v(Machine, Temperature, Humidity)                                          |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Am trying to understand the query because in the future thete will be more than 2 machines and i dont want to have a hardcoded machine

Comment: @CesarBecerra Updated with dynamic code generation.

Comment: I give up.. between Gordon Linoff,  sqlZim and John Cappelletti all the SQL questions are snipped before I can reload the page!